# How to limit a RoR cookies/session to 1 hour after being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, session-cookies, session-variables

I have a Ruby on Rails backend, currently using cookies & sessions to authenticate and login users. I believe session's default end time is when the user closes their browser, but I want the session to end 1 hour after being created.

Below are the controllers used to create the session and authenticate users:

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]
    include ::ActionController::Cookies
    
    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            render json: user
        else
            render json: {errors: "check email and password"}, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session.delete :user_id
        head :no_content
    end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]
    
    def show
        render json: @current_user
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include ActionController::Cookies

    before_action :authorize

    private

    def authorize
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        render json: {errors: "Not authorized"}, status: :unauthorized unless @current_user
    end
end
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that "session" is used to describe three different things: the *browser session* (which doesn't always mean that cookies are deleted), *the Rails session* which expires when the cookie expires or you reset the session by issuing a new cookie and *authentication sessions* which expire when you remove the user id from the session storage or expire the session storage.

Comment: For maximum security, would I want to ensure that all three of these are deleted at the 1 hour mark?

Comment: The browser session isn't actually in your control. That ends when the user closes their browser. You can set the cookie expiry to expire the Rails session after one hour but that doesn't neccissarily mean 1 hour from when the user signs in as rails creates the session identifier when you first visit the site. You make your authentication system expire by storing a timestamp along with the users id in the session (or in the database) and checking the timestamp when you authenticate the users. Thats how the Devise Timeoutable module works.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the expiry time in an intializer like so:

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_custom_session_key', expire_after: 1.hour.to_i
```

This will make sure your sessions expire after 1 hour. You can try with a smaller time frame like `1.minute` to verify.

Comment: So if I create an initializer called session_store.rb, do I put this word for word? Otherwise, how do I find the custom session key?

Comment: You can name the key to your liking as per the app name etc.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I'd made a mistake. It should be `1.hour.to_i` we should be converting it to integer value. Can you try with this? I've edited the answer as well